# Delete line containing word from FileB if word found in FileA

Tags: string, bash, sed, grep, comparison

FileA contains words and FileB contains strings.
How to, using sed/grep/awk (preferably), remove lines from FileB containing words found in FileA ?
Sample FileA:

> Word asdf
>  Word qwer
>  Word zxcv

Sample FileB:

> https://www.webaddress.com/point?a=asdf
>   http://www.webaddress.com/point?a=pert
>   https://www.webaddress.com/point?a=njil
>   http://www.webaddress.com/point?a=qwer
>   http://www.webaddress.com/point?a=zxcv

So, FileB should be changed to:

> http://www.webaddress.com/point?a=pert
>   https://www.webaddress.com/point?a=njil

**Speed is an issue here as both FileA and FileB can be huge. FileA and FileB can be sorted etc. if required.**

Comment: Can you remove the prefix `Word` in `FileA`, so it just contains the words?

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `grep`:

```bash
grep -v -f <(awk '{print $2}' FileA) FileB > tmp && mv tmp FileB
```

As commented by [Glenn Jackman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7552/glenn-jackman), you could also use the `-F` option for `grep` that would make it treat the pattern as fixed strings and would be more efficient.

The `<( )` syntax is referred to as [process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html) and produces a *file* containing the list of words, i.e. removes `word` from `fileA`.

The `-f` option for `grep` takes patterns from a file.  The `-v` option inverts matches.  So you get the lines in `fileB` that do not contain any word in the second column of `fileA`.

For your input, it'd produce:

```
http://www.webaddress.com/point?a=pert
https://www.webaddress.com/point?a=njil
```

Comment: The solution fails to edit FileB inline. So,`grep -v -f <(awk '{print $2}' FileA) FileB > temp && mv temp FileB`

Comment: Add more speed with grep `-F`, and `cut` would probably be a bit quicker than awk`

Comment: Are you sure that `cut` performs faster than `awk` ? Like `cut -d' ' -f2`

Comment: @glennjackman I agree with you on `-F`.  However, using `cut` might be a problem in case the words as separated by multiple spaces.

Comment: @myusuf, I'm not certain. I think that cut is a simpler executable. You would have to benchmark it: use [time](http://man.cx/time) or something similar

Answer (score 3):

```
grep -F -v -f <(sed 's/^Word //' FileA) FileB > FileB.new
```

- `-F` means to match fixed strings rather than regular expressions.
- `-v` means to output the lines that don't match
- `-f` means to take the list of strings to match from a filename
- `<(command line)` synthesizes a filename for the output of the command line
- The `sed` command removes the `Word` prefix from all the lines of `FileA`.

Comment: Does grep not have an inline option like `-i` ?

Comment: No, it doesn't write to files, it only writes to stdout.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an `awk` solution:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$2]++;next} {for (i in a) if ($0~i) next}8' fileA fileB
http://www.webaddress.com/point?a=pert
https://www.webaddress.com/point?a=njil
```